# Where can I find this result?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, schemes

A Noetherian scheme $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ the set of  derivations $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \kappa(x)=k$, is isomorphic to the Zariski tangent space $(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)^*$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reference is

> A. Borel, *Linear Algebraic Groups*, AG.15.4, p.34.